# Get count of related model in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Suppose I need to get a Post with the count of Comments. There are of course a number of ways of doing this. What is the best (or preferred) way of doing this?

1. Eager Load + then with route model binding to get count whenever Model is injected in route.

```
class Post extends Model {

    protected $withCount = [ 'comments' ];

    public function comments() 
    { 
         return $this->hasMany();
    }

}
```

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}', function (App\Post $post) {

    return $post;  // $post→comments_count gives count.

}
```

2. Cache the count

```
public function getCachedCommentsCountAttribute()
{
    return Cache::remember($this->getTable() . '.' . $this->getKey() . '.comments_count', 60*60*24, function () {
        return $this->comments()->count();  // posts.{id}.comments_count
    }); 
}
```

3. Other

What would be best performance wise?

Answer (score 0):

Why not both?
You can cache the count for a smaller amount of time and then, when the cache expires, just execute the query to get the updated count.

You could also tweak a little bit this approach by caching forever the count and invalidate the cache only when comment is inserted or deleted, by using [Eloquent Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#observers). This can be used if you know you will only use the Eloquent methods to insert or delete a comment. If you, for example, do a mass insert or execute a raw query for deleting a comment, events won't be triggered.

Comment: How may I utilise both? By using $this→withCount(‘comments’) in getCachedCommentsCountAttribute() instead of the relationship? Would it be better to eager load then go through the comments() relationship?

Comment: And with regards to invalidating cache, I was thinking of adding a touches property to the model, and the including the timestamp as part of the key so that when a comment is created or updated this will run the query again

Comment: You might add a `getCommentsCount()` method on the Post model, which will check first in cache if there's already the comments count. Otherwise it just loads the relationship and gets the count, storing it in cache so you will have it next time.
You don't need to touch the cache if you just edit a comment, since the count can't change.